# Implementing the Hashable Protocol in Swift with the DJB hash function

Tags: ios, swift, hashcode

A while back I made a custom String struct (see [github repo](https://github.com/suragch/MongolAppDevelopment-iOS/blob/master/Mongol%20App%20Componants/ScalarString.swift)) because of the difficulties in dealing with Mongolian Unicode rendering when using Swift `String` or `NSString` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift) and the accepted answer for more details). The struct is an array of `UInt32` so that it represents a string of Unicode scalar values.

The most difficult part (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438210/how-to-implement-the-hashable-protocol-in-swift-for-an-int-array-a-custom-strin/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664159/how-to-handle-hash-collisions-for-dictionaries-in-swift/) for my StackOverflow questions at the time) was making it conform to the Hashable Protocol so that it could be used as a Dictionary key.

For all that I can tell, everything has been working fine. However, since there was not a lot of documentation and guidance available about implementing the Hashable Protocol, I wanted to make sure that I did it right. Here is the relevant code:

```
struct ScalarString: SequenceType, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {

    private var scalarArray: [UInt32] = []

    // ...

    // hashValue needed to implement Hashable protocol
    var hashValue: Int {
        get {

            // DJB Hash Function
            var hash = 5381

            for(var i = 0; i < self.scalarArray.count; i++)
            {
                hash = ((hash << 5) &+ hash) &+ Int(self.scalarArray[i])
            }

            return hash
        }
    }

}

// Hashable also needs struct to conform to Equatable protocol
func ==(left: ScalarString, right: ScalarString) -> Bool {

    if left.length != right.length {
        return false
    }

    for var i = 0; i < left.length; ++i {
        if left.charAt(i) != right.charAt(i) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Hashable` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Hashable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfp/Hashable/s:vPSs8Hashable9hashValueSi) has only one single requirement:

> **Axiom:** `x == y` implies `x.hashValue == y.hashValue`.

So let's start with your implementation of `==`:

> ```
> // Hashable also needs struct to conform to Equatable protocol
> func ==(left: ScalarString, right: ScalarString) -> Bool {
>
>     if left.length != right.length {
>         return false
>     }
>
>     for var i = 0; i < left.length; ++i {
>         if left.charAt(i) != right.charAt(i) {
>             return false
>         }
>     }
>
>     return true
> }
> ```

Looking up the definitions of `length` and `charAt()` it is clear
that here simply the `left.scalarArray` and `right.scalarArray`
arrays are checked for equality. So the operator can equivalently
but simpler be implemented as

```
// Hashable also needs struct to conform to Equatable protocol
func ==(left: ScalarString, right: ScalarString) -> Bool {
    return left.scalarArray == right.scalarArray
}
```

From this representation it becomes obvious that your `hashValue`
implementation is *correct*: It is computed from the `scalarArray`
property, so equal objects have the same hash value.

The `hashValue` computed property can be simplified using
`reduce()`, note also that for a read-only property, you need
not put the getter method inside a `get { }` block:

```
// hashValue (to implement Hashable protocol)
var hashValue: Int {
    return self.scalarArray.reduce(5381) {
        ($0 << 5) &+ $0 &+ Int($1)
    }
}
```

A different question would be how "good" the hash is.
The Swift language does not make any requirements here. Always
returning `0` would be valid, but of course ineffective when
building large dictionaries.

It may be interesting in this context that the hash value of 
the Foundation type `NSArray` is simply the number of elements,
regardless of the contents.

In your case, the DJB hash function is a well-known hash method
for strings, so I do not see any reasons not to use it.

---

**Update:** As of **Swift 4.1,** the compiler can synthesize 
`Equatable` and `Hashable` for types conformance automatically, if all 
members conform to Equatable/Hashable ([SE0185](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md)). And as of **Swift 4.2,**
a high-quality hash combiner is built-in into the Swift standard
library ([SE-0206](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md)).

Therefore there is no need anymore to define your own hashing function,
it suffices to declare the conformance:

```
struct ScalarString: Hashable, ... {

    private var scalarArray: [UInt32] = []

    // ...
}
```

Comment: After your review, I've been meaning to rewrite my former SO answer. I finally got around to it today. If you have time, I would be grateful if you would look it over to make sure that there are no glaring errors and that I did not misunderstand anything in your answer. [Here is the link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31444592)